# How do you use Roundup issue tracker?

Tags: issue-tracking

Roundup issue tracker is pretty minimalistic by default, and it does not bring any specific workflow with itself. It was once [called](http://rephrase.net/days/08/10/roundup-dreamhost) ‘so configurable that it’s probably better described as a lightweight tracker-oriented framework.’

Have you ever used Roundup extensively or seen some interesting use cases? If so, please share an example.

(If you don’t consider your workflow special enough, at least tell how do you understand & utilize `superseder` field in the default ‘classic’ template, which alone could be interpreted differently—see *old.nabble.com/Superseder-td13792131.html*)

Comment: My fault, this question should be a community wiki. Though moderator is needed for conversion.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm using it for the [Python bug tracker](http://bugs.python.org). We have the customization [publically available](http://svn.python.org/projects/tracker/instances/python-dev/).

In addition, I also use it for students to submit exercises (assignments are somewhat similar to components/milestones; solutions are similar to bug reports, except for access control). However, the code for this is not public.

Comment: Interesting use in education, thanks! The ideas count—code is optional. Sorry, can't upvote yet here.